# flask marshmallow hyperlinkrelated field query params

Tags: flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I am using the flask-marshmallow package's `HyperlinkRelatedField` and wanted to know if it was possible to add query-string parameters dynamically with one of the provided fields (either a field from flask marshmallow or marshmallow like `HyperlinkRelatedField`). I want this:

```
/api/v1/cars?manufacturer=12
```

Where manufacturer Id in the querystring is the ID of the serialized object and cars is the hyperlink related field.
I am working with a flattened API so linking fields with a many relationship would need to be done with filtering So this would be something like the Schema (this doesn't work but an example of what I am looking to achieve):

```
class ManufacturerSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    cars = HyperlinkRelated('api.carslist', params={'manufacturer': '<id>'})

    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        sqla_session = db.session
```

Where:

```
manufacturer = Manufacturer.query.get(1)  # ID is 1
ms = ManufacturerSchema()
ms.dump(manufacturer)
```

Would return:

```
{
...
'cars': '/api/v1/cars?manufacturer=1',
...
}
```

How would I achieve this? Is it possible with the provided Marshmallow/Flask-Marshmallow Fields, or would I have to subclass HyperLinkRelated or Field?